# Access Error after using SendObject

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem using the SendObject function in Access.

Current Access version: 2013

I created a test button in an empty form to test my command. When I use SendObject without any parameter or only with "acSendNoObject" it works.

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject
DoCmd.SendObject
```

As expected both work fine. The mailclient opens correctly and a new email is created without any edits.

But when I want to use more parameters Access crashes.
For example:

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , "email@email.com", , , "Subject", Text, True, False
```

In theory the code works. But Access freezes with the "Application has stopped working.." window. After pressing cancel the mailclient opens up and all parameters are inserted correctly. So with "To:", with "Subject"... Everything is fine, but Access crashes every time.

The used mailclient is "Amicron Mailoffice". I tested the edit of Win.ini. I found this solution, so it says to change the "MAPI=1" entry in the Win.ini to "MAPIX=1". It didn't help.

I hope you can understand my problem an maybe here is someone who has a good idea to solve it.

The version with:

```
FollowHyperlink "mailto:email@email.com"
```

It works, but with this I cannot change the subject or add an attachment I think. I think the mailto Hyperlink is not made for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim recipient_ As String
    recipient_ = "some email address"

Dim subject_ As String
    subject_ = "Some text"

DoCmd.SendObject To:=recipient_, Subject:=subject_, EditMessage:=False
```

MSDN: [DoCmd.SendObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-sendobject-method-access)

Comment: It didn't work. The same problem as described before. Access freezes with the same error window.

The mailclient opens up with the message sent. So in theory the link between the programs works..